# Repurpose a MagSafe 2 Charger for USB-C

Tags: charger, usb-c, apple

Hi Mac Owner here that is now dealing with cable hell...

I have an [inexpensive 60W MagSafe 2 charger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01KNPQFUA) that I was wondering if I was able to rewire the connector for USB-C. I have experience with electronics from a repair stand point, but almost zero electrical theory.

Is this possible? Where do I start?

Comment: I'd start by reading the specs, there are a few hundred pages. But most likely no, because on some USB-C devices use a digital handshake before supplying power. The voltage can also be different.

Comment: Your charger is 16.5V, USB is 5V. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: I was looking for answers on an idea. I didn't think that this was the wrong forum to ask nor did I think green field questions wouldn't be welcome. I apologize for joining this stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charging over USB C uses "USB power delivery" to negotiate the voltage and current, starting at a "safe" 5V.

So no you can't really convert a generic power brick to a USB C laptop power brick without significant extra electronics.

Comment: I'm assuming the newer chargers are significantly different.